# Error Angular ngx-toastr

Tags: angular

Hola estoy intentando usar ngx-toastr pero me sale este error:

> ERROR in node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-injector.d.ts(1,20):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/xampp/htdocs/project-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no
>   exported member 'InjectFlags'.

Me pueden ayudar? Gracias

Comment: Como puedo poner una version de ngx-toastr mas antigua?

Comment: npm i ngx-toastr@x.x.x, donde `x.x.x` es la versión de la directiva.